# What does it mean by "no mere shuffling of commercial cards" in this context?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, terminology

What does it mean by "no mere shuffling of commercial cards" in this context? Also would like to know what is a "commercial card" in a time like 1892 (Under a British command)?

> "... as long as the peasantry in these lands are (as they are) practically
> starving, and the irrigation works practically neglected, the
> responsibility for such a state of affairs must lie with the rulers ;
> and naturally **no mere shuffling of commercial cards**, or encouragement
> of an export trade which brings fortunes into the hands of a few
> tea-planters and merchants, can be expected to make things better."
>
> -From Adam's Peak to Elephanta (1892)-

Comment: Do you mean [_From Adam's Peak to Elephanta_](https://amzn.com/8120612337)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Shuffling the cards" here is a metaphor for redistributing the advantages held by various players in a game, and "commercial" indicates the particular "game" which is being played.

What the author is saying is that changing the structure or rules of commerce, of the export trade, merely redistributes the rewards among various members of the commercial class, the people involved in the export trade; it will do nothing to improve the condition for people outside that class, who are not participants in the commerce "game" and are not dealt any of the "cards".

Comment: But it's not "shuffling **the** cards". Which makes me wonder if "commercial cards" aren't real things. It's a bit early for Rolodexes, but card reorganizing would seem to fit the context as well. Either way, the result is the same - a redistribution which excludes the peasantry.

Comment: @PhilSweet I agree with StoneyB, it reads like a metaphor to me. A bit like 'another throw of the commercial dice' but with the implication of changing the conditions of the game. To extend the metaphor shuffling the deck only changes conditions for the players, not those excluded from the casino altogether.

Comment: @BoldBen The thing is, business cards as we know them today were only just becoming ubiquitous among merchants at this time. These sorts of cards were earlier used as visitation cards by high society, and there would have been a need to make the distinction. There were also postal cards at this time (for mass mailings), and some of those were used as business cards also. The earliest reference for *business card* I've found is 1896, just 4 years after the book, and refers to a repurposed postal card. It makes clear they are already widely used and the term would be instantly understood.

Comment: @PhilSweet The earliest use of "**commercial** card" in Google Books, however, is 1974. And surely speaking of "shuffling" cards is going to be associated by the reader with playing cards?

Comment: As a metaphor, I read it as a shuffling of people, with cards, real ones, being the stand-in for people. "shuffling the cabinet" and "shuffling the administration" get plenty of hits. I think the "shuffling of people" is a separate usage and doesn't bring to mind playing cards any more than the shuffling of feet does. Interestingly, the ODO groups "shuffling papers" and "shuffling money between .." with shuffling people's positions, but lists "shuffling cards" separately.

Answer (score 1):

*Commercial cards* in this context likely refers to *post cards*, which were used to propagandize such subjects as [World War I](https://books.google.com/books?id=pmaHCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&dq=commercial%20postcards&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI8Lb5nI3QAhWjilQKHU5TDjMQ6AEIYTAI#v=onepage&q=commercial%20postcards&f=false) and [women's suffrage](http://womansuffragememorabilia.com/woman-suffrage-memorabilia/post-cards/) (both for and against in the latter).

In the [Woman Suffrage Memorabilia](http://womansuffragememorabilia.com/woman-suffrage-memorabilia/post-cards/) site, the term *commercial cards* is used to distinguish cards produced by commercial publishers from cards produced by the suffragists themselves.

In the paragraph in question, the author is observing that simply handing out commercial cards to 'spin' the situation would do nothing to actually improve things.